# How to use a string' value as an object name

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, object, variables

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
user_id = 12345
"user_id" = user("...")  # "user" is my class
# I want to replace "user_id" with "12345"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It's bad Python style to create variable names at runtime.  The idea of creating names on the fly is a carry over from languages like Basic which don't have good dictionary and list structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need this, you're better off with a dict:

```
my_objs = {}
user_id = 12345
my_objs[user_id] = User()
print(my_objs)
```

Then the output would be:

```
{12345: <__main__.User object at 0x123456789abc>}
```

You can always fetch the object with either of these:

```
another_id = 12345
my_objs[another_id]

my_objs[12345]
```

---

If you really, really need this but can't use a dict, `getattr` and `setattr` may help:

```
user_name = "hahaha"
setattr(__import__(__name__), user_name, User())

print(hahaha)

new_name = "hahaha"
assert hahaha is getattr(__import__(__name__), new_name)
```

which will generate the same output and the assertion will pass.

Note this method isn't going to work all well inside a function, it's only good at module level.